# My android studio not responding if i click any option of main menu tool

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

My android studio not responding if i click any option of main menu tool. The menu bar is not available. Such as File->New->New Project or File -> Open. Main menu tool not responding. But coding is no problem include shortcuts is also ok.